# Rails 3 before_destroy triggered twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

in a Rails 3 application there are two models assinged to each other by **belongs_to** and **has_one**. On both sides there is **:depended => :destroy** configured for this association. 
now I had to add a **:before_destroy** callback in one of these models. the problem is now that this callback is triggered twice when an entity which includes this callback is destroyed. When I remove **:depended => :destroy** in the other model, it's triggered only once. So it seems this i causing the problem.

is there an elegant way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

:dependent
    Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is destroyed

dependent destroy must be alone in a model

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_one :position, dependent: :destroy
```

Sorry for my english XD

Comment: I know what it does, but since it's configured on both sides, it's causing the described problem